# Python Selenium StaleElementReferenceException while iterating through Select options

Tags: jquery, python, selenium

I have been tasked with providing a selenium test (using Python) on a webpage for which I did not write the source code (I don't know much about web development, but from what I was told, it was written using D3 and JQuery). The website generates graphs, and there are a few dropdown menus with options. I'm trying to create every possible graph with these options. To do so, I create a Select object from the dropdown menu WebElement and extract the text of each option in the dropdown. Later on, I use this text to recursively go through each dropdown and enter each valid option to generate the graphs. However, I sometimes (not always, and it seems to be relatively random) encounter a StaleElementReferenceException while trying to extract this list of options, and it is because of the below code (it happens on the `options.append(op.get_attribute("text"))` line). I have been searching previous questions and documentation on this exception, and I have yet to find an answer than helps me.

```
#find all of the options 
# create list of string options before, so as to avoid StaleElementReferenceException's
# as much as possible
el = driver.find_element(By.ID,node.element)
d = Select(el)
options = [] 
for op in d.options:
    try:
        options.append(op.get_attribute("text"))
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'StaleElementReferenceException getting text from \'' + node.element + '\' element'
```

Any input is very helpful! Thank you.

EDIT: Here is an HTML snippet example of one of the dropdowns:

```
<select class="dropdown" id="datatype" name="datatype" style="display: none;">
    <option value="solar_radiation" selected="selected">solar radiation</option>
    <option value="windspeed">windspeed</option>
    <option value="airtemperature">airtemperature</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have actually looked through that documentation already, and I understand pretty well what the exception means. I'm just not sure why I'm getting it in this instance, or how to avoid it.

Comment: does selecting an option refresh the page or change the DOM?  If so, that is causing your problem.  you are using a reference to an element that has changed

Comment: I believe it changes the DOM, as elements in other lists depend on the option you choose. In the above code, though, I'm not even selecting any options. All I'm doing is iterating through the available options and saving their values in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspicious `d = Select(el)`

If you just want to get all the texts, maybe you can do like:

```
optionNodes = driver.find_element_by_id("datatype").find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
options = []
for op in optionNodes:
    options.append(op.get_attribute("text"))
```

If the code above doesn't work (strange, though), maybe you can try to execute script, like:

```
driver.execute_script("return Array.apply(null, document.getElementById('datatype').options).map(function (option) {return option.text})");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. Still same StaleElementReferenceException on that get_attribute line

Comment: Could you provide the html for the Select?

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'options' of null` Perhaps I am executing this wrong, I've never used Javascript before.

Comment: I used the id = 'datatype' in the code sample, but maybe you have a different id for your select?

Comment: Yes, the id is held in `node.element`, as above in the original post. I replaced 'datatype' with this and got the exception, and then I went through manually and typed in the id's to ensure they were correct, and got the same exception.

Comment: How about you trying to run the command `Array.apply(null, document.getElementById('datatype').options).map(function (option) {return option.text})` in the browser's console?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null
    at <anonymous>` in the console as well. However, I was able to successfully execute the following script in the console: `Array.apply(null, document.querySelector('#datatype').options).map(function (option) {return option.text})`, and this successfully returned the list of options in the console. When I call driver.execute_script() in Python, though, this returns None. How do I get this list to return into python? Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: I updated the answer with "return Array.apply..", could you check again?
And I think, maybe something wrong with `By.Id` in your browser. So maybe you can use your original code, but instead of `find_element(By.Id)`, you can try to use `By.CssSelector`

Comment: Oddly, `driver.execute_script(script)` returns `None`, but when I execute the exact script (printed it to terminal, copied into console and ran it), it successfully returns the list. I tried my original code replacing ID with CSS Selector, and I still have the same problem: occasional, random `StaleElementReferenceException`s

Comment: For `driver.execute_script`: I would debug and see if anything wrong with the driver.
For the `StaleElementReferenceException`, try to use Waits until element presenced http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've been trying to use explicit waits to solve this problem for quite some time. This is a bit tough. The exception happens in that for loop--NOT when finding the dropdown list beforehand--, on the .get_attribute() call, to get the option's text element. If I wanted to implement an explicit wait, I would still have to call `EC.presence_of_element_located(By.<something>,op.get_attribute(<something>))`. So, in order to call the explicit wait, I still have to call the line that triggers the exception, and this doesn't help me.

Comment: Did you try to put wait for `el = driver.find_element(By.ID,node.element)`? 
And maybe you can print out `el.get_attribute("class")`?

Comment: And I think it's good to check why `driver.execute_script` doesn't work. Make a simple script and call `execute_script`.

Comment: It would appear that the execute script is working now... I must have typed something in wrong somewhere. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty workaround will be to iterate over the options list with indexes and repopulate the list when you encounter the exception

```
el = driver.find_element(By.ID,node.element)
select = Select(el)
options = select.options
options_texts = []
for i in range len(options)):
try:
    options_texts.append(options[i].get_attribute("text"))
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    el = driver.find_element(By.ID,node.element)
    select = Select(el)
    options = select.options
```